# Spark Streaming: Multiple Kerberos Authenication

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kerberos

I'm working on a Spark Streaming application that will consume the messages from a secure kafka topic, and push those messages to Kerberos enabled HDFS.

I've the keytab and krb5.conf files for both Kafka and Hadoop.

I'm running into issues here as I'm able to obtain a kerberos ticket for only one realm (either Kafka or HDFS) at a time.

Is there a way (apart from cross realm authentication) to authenicate on both Kafka and HDFS using Spark streaming ?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this ? I am facing same issue